# Counting number of squares in Sierpinski carpet with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

This method originates the Sierpinski carpet by steps with recursion, like so:
[Sierpinski carpet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26AP8.png)

The problem I'm having is counting the number of squares in each step(variable "deep"), the numbers would be:

1. Number of squares: 1
2. Number of squares: 9
3. Number of squares: 73
4. Number of squares: 585
5. Number of squares: 4681

Method printSquares:

```
    private int printSquares(Graphics g, int xi, int yi, int width, int height,     int deep) {

    int subW = width / 3;
    int subH = height / 3;
    g.fillRect(xi + subW, yi + subH, subW - 1, subH - 1);


    if(deep!=1) {

        printSquares(g, xi, yi, subW, subH, deep-1);
        printSquares(g, xi + subW, yi, subW, subH, deep-1);
        printSquares(g, xi + 2 * subW, yi, subW, subH, deep-1);
        printSquares(g, xi, yi + subH, subW, subH, deep-1);
        printSquares(g, xi, yi + 2 * subH, subW, subH, deep-1);
        printSquares(g, xi + subW, yi + subH, subW, subH, deep-1);
        printSquares(g, xi + subW, yi + 2 * subH, subW, subH, deep-1);
        printSquares(g, xi + 2 * subW, yi + subH, subW, subH, deep-1);
        printSquares(g, xi + 2 * subW, yi + 2 * subH, subW, subH, deep-1);

    }

    return nSquare;}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice carefully, 8 additional squares are added for each of the squares generated in the previous step. So,

1. In step 1, we have `1 square`.
2. In step 2, we have `1 + 8^1 (additional squares)`.
3. In step 3, we have `1 + 8 + 8^2 (64 additional squares)`.

   In step n, we have `1 + 8 + ... + 8^(n-1) (8^n-1 additional squares)`.

#### What is that? A [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Now, we sum this (see the formula in the link above):

Here, the first term(`a`) is `1` and common ratio(`r`) is `8`.

`1 + 8 + 8 * 8 + ..... + 8^(n-1) = 1*(8^n - 1)/(8-1) = (8^n - 1)/7`

Let's test it:

```
1. If depth = 1: Squares = (8^1-1)/7 = 7/7 = 1
2. If depth = 2: Squares = (8^2-1)/7 = 63/7 = 9
3. If depth = 3: Squares = (8^3-1)/7 = 511/7 = 73
```

**Computational Complexity**: `O(1)`

**Recursive relation**, just in case:

Let function `f` denote the total number of squares at depth `n`, then:

`f(n) = f(n-1) + 8^(n-1), f(1) = 1`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, have a great day!